# Migrating from EF Core 2 to EF Core 3 ... could not be translated

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

After upgrading my project from ef core 2.2 to ef core 3.1 almost all of my entity framework LINQ queries are broken

Here is an example I have a problem with:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(b => b.IsDeleted == __displayIsDeleted_0)
> .Where(b => __properties_1
> .Any(p => p.GetValue((object)b) != null && p.GetValue((object)b).ToString().IndexOf(
> value: __8__locals1_query_2,
> comparisonType: InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.)'

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereDynamic<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> sourceList, string query)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            return sourceList;
        }
        try
        {

            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead && x.CanWrite && !x.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual);

            //Expression
            sourceList = sourceList.Where(c =>
                properties.Any(p => p.GetValue(c) != null && p.GetValue(c).ToString()
                   /* .Contains(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)*/
                   .IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 ));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return sourceList;
    }
```

If possible, tell me what changes I should make to this code

Comment: IQueryable is doing nothing here as you have already brought the entire table into memory. Just saying this doesn't look great for any kind of performance. You may as well force `IQueryable<T> sourceList` to be a List at this point. This is why `ToList` was called in the example answer. Ef 2 was just doing this for you when it shouldn't, as otherwise you wouldn't know the performance was dirty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core 2 executed code on client side when it was not possible to translate C# to SQL. With this option being disabled in EF Core 3 by default, you could achieve same behaviour with code below

```
sourceList = sourceList
     .ToList()
     .Where(c =>
         properties.Any(p => p.GetValue(c) != null && p.GetValue(c).ToString()
              .IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 ))
     .AsQueryable();
```

More about client evaluation in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)

Comment: tank you .
If possible, introduce me to a link with a full explanation of this topic

Comment: added a link to answer

Comment: Note, this type of query is exactly why the change was made. EVERY row in the database is returned. Any that don't match the filter are just thrown away resulting in a lot of wasted bandwidth that only gets worse as your database grows. Think hard about how you can add a Where clause that translates to SQL *before* the ToList call.

Comment: @bricelam I wonder why they even considered client evaluation before

Comment: I had looked for an article on this topic previously. Thank you for pointing us to it :)